# Redirect to different page on django

Tags: python, django, django-views

This funtion is to update an order, i would like to be redirected to the customer profile page where i can find all this customer's orders. on the costumer profile i have all orders listed with option to modify or delete. i would like to modify and to redirected to the costumer profile page which the url is :

path("customer_profile/int:pk/", views.Customer_profile, name="customer_profile")

```
def OrderUpdate(request, pk):
order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
form = OrderForm(instance=order)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('orders')

context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'orders/order_form.html', context)
```

Comment: So the same page as the `orderUpdate` function?

Comment: Can you add to the question your `urls.py` and the url or view that you want to redirect to

Comment: i just update the question, thks

Comment: return redirect('customer_profile')

Comment: the prob is on this details, customer_profile need a pk because there are many costumers

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders'))
```

[For More info check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)